# How to pass the output of one command as the command-line argument to another?

Tags: bash, shell, command-line

So I have a script that, when I give it two addresses, will search two HTML links:

```
echo "http://maps.google.be/maps?saddr\=$1\&daddr\=$2" | sed 's/ /%/g'
```

I want to send this to `wget` and then save the output in a file called `temp.html`. I tried this, but it doesn't work. Can someone explain why and/or give me a solution please?

```
#!/bin/bash
url = echo "http://maps.google.be/maps?saddr\=$1\&daddr\=$2" |  sed 's/ /%/g'
wget $url
```

Comment: For debugging something like this checking your variable values (by echo-ing them to the terminal) often gets you to the solution quickly.

Answer (score 106, accepted):

You can use backticks (`) to evaluate a command and substitute in the command's output, like:

```
echo "Number of files in this directory: `ls | wc -l`"
```

In your case:

```
wget `echo http://maps.google.be/maps?saddr\=$1\&daddr\=$2 | sed 's/ /%/g'`
```

Comment: See [Why `$(...)` is preferred over backticks](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/082).

Comment: Note that `ls | wc -l` will count the number of lines outputted by `ls`, not the number of files in the current directory. To count files, use `shopt -s nullglob dotglob; set -- *; printf '%s\n' "$#"`.

Answer (score 43):

You could use "xargs".  A trivial example:

```
ls -1 *.c | sort -n | xargs cat
```

You would have to take care that xargs doesn't split its stdin into two or more invocations of the comman ("cat" in the example above).

Comment: I ended up here, because I couldn't remember this command name. My favorite use case was indeed: xargs -I % some_command --input=% -e -t -c (I put it here as a note for others that follow the same trace)

Comment: Hi @Bruce Ediger! I randomly stumbled across you when googling this :D Hope you're doing well!

Comment: Hey @frederix who let you in here? I see they will let just anyone in here these days! LOLOLOLOL

Answer (score 18):

you're not actually executing your url line :

```
#!/bin/sh
url="$(echo http://maps.google.be/maps?saddr\=$1\&daddr\=$2 | sed 's/ /%/g')"
wget $url
```

Answer (score 6):

It seems you could use a combination of the answers here. I'm guessing you are wanting to replace space chars with their escaped ASCII values in the URL.

To do this, you need to replace them with `%20`, not just `%`.  Here's a solution that should give you a complete answer:

```
$ wget $(echo http://maps.google.be/maps\?saddr\=$1\&daddr\=$2 | sed -e 's/\ /\%20/g') -q -O temp.html
```

- The `$( ... )` indicate that the enclosed command should be interpreted first, and the result sent to `wget`. Notice I escaped the space and `%` chars in the `sed` command to prevent them from being misinterpreted.
- The `-q` option for `wget` prevents processing output from the command being printed to the screen (handy for scripting when you don't care about the in-work status) and the `-O` option specifies the output file.

FYI, if you don't want to save the output to a file, but just view it in the terminal, use `-` instead of a filename to indicate stdout.

Answer (score 5):

`xargs` is the best option to place output from a command into the argument of another command.

Suppose the output of command1 is `3` and you want your next command to take this `3` as an argument, you will  want something like this

```
command2 3(which is output of 1st command) 4 5
```

So, for this you can do like so

```
command1 | xargs -I{} command2 {} 4 5
```

Where 4 and 5 are the other two arguments that may be needed for `command2`.

You can place the curly brackets in the position where you want the output from first command.

So, use

```
command1 | xargs -I{} command2 {}
```

Comment: Can u elaborate? Give a example... Because i tried it here and did'nt work. I did'nt understand. I tried: ps -fA | grep {} | head -n 1 | xargs -I{} lsof -i:80 | awk -F ' ' '{if(NR>1)print $2}' {} 

It did'nt work... Command lsof + awk gets PID of proccess, and ps + grep outputs what proccess has this PID.

Comment: Errors: 

→ awk: cannot open {} (No such file or directory)
→ xargs: lsof: terminated by signal 13

Answer (score 3):

wget also accepts stdin with the `-` switch.

If you want to save the output in a file, use the `-O` switch.

```
echo http://maps.google.be/maps?saddr\=$1\&daddr\=$2 | sed 's/ /%/g' | wget -i- -O temp.html
```

Answer (score 0):

*Note: I prefer the `xargs` option over the next one.*

---

Following is another solution using a function that provides the output of the `first command argument` as elements into the `$i` variable to the `second command argument`

#### Definition

```bash
my_lambda() { for i in "$1"; do eval ${2}; done; }
```

#### Usage

```bash
my_lambda "$(find ~/Documents | grep *.pdf)" "ls -l $i"
```

Comment: 'eval' is a common misspelling of 'evil'. If eval is the answer, surely you are asking the wrong question. See http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/048