# I want to execute man command on another command that I get as input from a file

Tags: linux, command-line, man

I have a file that contains multiple commands, ls,echo,ps etc. I want to find with a terminal command which command occurs most (have the most appearances on the file) and then execute man to it. For example my file contain ls ls ps I must execute man ls. The form of the file is : multiple lines and in every line I have a  command only.

file example:

```
ls
ls
ps
echo
man
cp
rm
```

Answer (score 2):

Sort the file, count the number of times each word occurs in sequence, sort again but this time on the number (in decreasing order), grab the first one and remove the number (assuming the original list only contains single words with no whitespace):

```
sort file | uniq -c | sort -nr | head -n 1 | awk '{ print $2 }'
```

For the given file, this would produce `ls`.

To call `man` for this command:

```
man "$( sort file | uniq -c | sort -nr | head -n 1 | awk '{ print $2 }' )"
```

Or just

```
man "$( awk '++c[$1] && c[$1] > m { mc=$1; m=c[$1] } END { print mc }' file )"
```

Related:

- [find n most frequent words in a file](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/41479)
- [What's the easiest way to make a list of most common words in a list?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/62056)
- [How to pass the output of one command as the command-line argument to another?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/4782)